# Is there some way I can fixed this the error that says findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode everytime i click the mui datatable?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

This is what the error says everytime i'll click the muidatatable. Is there some way I can fix this? If it was not fixed, will it cause some future problems when I'm going to deploy the project?

```
index.js:1 Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference. Learn more about using refs safely here:
```

This is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";
import {firestore} from './../../../firebase/firebase.utils';

class UserTable extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { users: []};
      }

    columns = ["Display Name", "Email", "Address"];
    options = {
        filter: true,
        selectableRows: 'none',
      };
  

    componentDidMount() {
        firestore.collection('users')
            .get()
            .then( snapshot => {
                const users = []
                 snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    const data = doc.data()
                    users.push({"Display Name":data.displayName, 'Email': data.email, 'Address' : data.address});
                })
                this.setState({ users : users})
                // console.log(snapshot)
            })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }   

    render() {
        return this.state.users ? (
            <MUIDataTable
              title={"List of Users"}
              columns={this.columns}
              data={this.state.users}
              options={this.options}
            />
          ) : (
            <div>Loading...</div>
          );
        }
      }
 
export default UserTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this error, you must update @material-ui/core to v5 or remove StrictMode.
[Github issue](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables/issues/1543)

Comment: I still get the same error whenever I'll click the mui-datatable